# Round numbers in 15min javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do a select box with 4 options
00,15,30,45

I want to take the current time and round it to 15 min increments, and have the value change.

I have

```
current_min = start_date.getMinutes();
$('#event-hour').val(current_min);
```

I played with this `roundedMinutes=(15*Math.floor(enteredMinutes/15))` but i couldn't get it to work right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Math.round` instead of `Math.floor` and everything should be ok-- other than that, your equation for rounding to the nearest `n` is correct.

Answer (score 2):

```
currentTimeRounded = (15*Math.round(date.getMinutes()/15));

js> (15*Math.round(date.getMinutes()/15));
15
```

Works just fine for me.

Comment: for this solution make sure you deal with 60 value properly by adding 1 hour and reseting minutes to 0